# error $.supersized({

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins, supersized

I built this header template for a homepage redesign. Everything works well locally with MAMP but there is a problem when I load the header file onto the client's folder. I continue to get this error in firebug: TypeError: $.supersized is not a function

I looked at every website, every post on the topic and nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'supersized_style', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/supersized/css/supersized.css');
wp_enqueue_script( 'supersized_js',get_bloginfo('template_url').'/supersized/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'supersized_js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/supersized/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'supersized_js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/supersized/js/supersized.shutter.min.js', array('jquery'));?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">  

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
             $.supersized({

                //Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide (0 is random)
                slide_interval          :   5000,   //Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
                new_window              :   0,      //Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   2,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,      //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
                image_path              :   'supersize/img/', //Default image path

                //Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   0,      //Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
                fit_portrait            :   0,      //Portrait     images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                //Components
                navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,      //Thumbnail navigation
                slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
                slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
                slides                  :   [           //Slideshow Images
{image : 'wp-content/themes/photo_philanthropy/supersized/slides/calvert.jpg', 
title : '<div id="tab"><h6 class="cap-tab">WHAT WE DO</h6><br/></div><div id="image-cap"><div id="main-title" ><h6 class="main-title" style="font-size:22px;line-height:135%;">PhotoPhilanthropy brings together photographers and non-profit organizations to create images that change the world.</h6></div></div><div id="photo-cap"><p class="photo-cap">WORLD VISION&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PHOTO BY MARY F. CALVERT</p><p class="photo-cap" style="line-height:200%;">According to Human Rights Watch, local civilians continue to suffer from widespread instances of rape by Congolese forces.</p></div>', 
 url : 'photophilanthropy.org/www/blogmedia/wp-        content/themes/photophil/supersized/slides/'},  

{image : 'wp-content/themes/photo_philanthropy/supersized/slides/wakatobi.jpg', 
title : '<div id="tab"><h6 class="cap-tab">GRANTS FOR CHANGE</h6><br/></div><div id="image-cap"><div id="main-title"><h6 class="main-title" style="font-size:36px;">EMPOWERING NON-PROFITS</h6><br/><h6 class="subheading">Showcasing collaborations between photographers and nonprofits on the frontlines of social change.</h6></div></div><div id="photo-cap"><p class="photo-cap">WORLD WILDLIFE FUND&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PHOTO BY JAMES MORGAN</p><p class="photo-cap" style="line-height:200%;">Enal plays with his pet shark, Wakatobi, Indonesia.</p></div>',
url : 'photophilanthropy.org/www/blogmedia/wp-        content/themes/photophil/supersized/slides/'},  

{image : 'wp-content/themes/photo_philanthropy/supersized/slides/valdisteno.jpg', 
title : '<div id="tab"><h6 class="cap-tab">EXHIBITIONS FOR CHANGE</h6><br/></div><div id="image-cap"><div id="main-title"><h6 class="main-title" style="font-size:36px;">AGENTS FOR CHANGE</h6><br/><h6 class="subheading">Recognizing the photgraphers who focus their lens on today’s most critical issues.</h6></div></div></div><div id="photo-cap"><p class="photo-cap">THE UMBRELLA FOUNDATION&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PHOTO BY NICOLETTA VALDISTENO</p><p class="photo-cap" style="line-height:200%;">A young girl in the Kathmandu Valley moves bricks after they have dried and are now ready to be cooked.</p></div>',
url : 'photophilanthropy.org/www/blogmedia/wp-content/themes/photophil/supersized/slides/'}, 

{image : 'wp-content/themes/photo_philanthropy/supersized/slides/samburu.jpg', 
title : '<div id="tab"><h6 class="cap-tab">THE UNITED NATIONS</h6><br/></div><div id="image-cap"><div id="main-title" style="padding-top:5px;"><h6 class="main-title" style="font-size:44px;">BEHIND THIS FACE IS A STORY</h6><br/></div></div><div id="photo-cap"><p class="photo-cap"> BLUE PLANET NETWORK and THE SAMBURU PROJECT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PHOTO BY RUDI DUNDAS</p><p class="photo-cap"style="line-height:200%;">The Face of Water is the story of the women of Samburu who have spent lifetimes struggling to provide water for their families.</p></div>',
url : 'photophilanthropy.org/www/blogmedia/wp-content/themes/photophil/supersized/slides/'} ]

            }); 
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: http://images.sodahead.com/polls/001294195/Samuel_Johnson_by_Joshua_ReynoldsWHUT20impact20con100_answer_5_xlarge.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your supersized script doesn't get loaded by the browser for some reason. Check logs of both web server and firebug to make sure that supersized.3.2.7.min.js gets loaded. If there's a bunch of 404's - web server logs will clarify why.

Answer (score 0):

I think its getting conflict with another custom  javascript file. Recheck all jQuery script whether other .js are initiated using `jQuery(document).ready` function or by simply using     `jQuery(function($))` .

"*TypeError: $.supersized is not a function*" is a common error thrown by firebug due to jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had to place it using:

```
jQuery(function($){

$.supersized({...
...
});

});
```

Hope that helps